# How to dismiss multiple view controllers which have been presented not pushed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, popup, viewcontroller

**Scenario:**

I need to show 3 or more popups one after the other on button click in each popup. I have created a different `viewcontroller` and `xib` files for each popup. So for displaying each popup I have used `presentViewController` instead of `pushViewController`.

That is, I have used this:

`[self presentPopupViewController:searchPopUpView animationType:0];`

instead of

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:searchPopUpView animated:YES];`

For dismissing a popup, the following code has been written:

```
[self dismissPopupViewControllerWithanimationType:0];
```

**Issue:**

The popups are displaying perfectly, but the background gets darker and darker whenever a popup shows up. After all popups have been dismissed I have to finally click on the blank screen to remove those darker parts. How to overcome this issue?

Comment: Can you add UI Images.

Comment: [self presentViewController:yourobj animated:YES completion:nil]; and dismiss [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Friend i have some sort of it will help you i think.

Comment: check your `[self.childViewControllers count]` then run for loop takeout viewcontroller one by one & remove it from parentViewController, this trick will help you.

Comment: @Lalitkumar it doesn't work like that. If I added those code, then it will be showing as a full vie controller not as a popup

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using **MJPopupViewController** to show pop-up.

If it is so, Then try this.

Suppose there is a **controllerA** from which you want to show a pop-up controller **popupControllerB**.

Then in your **controllerA** add **Notifications Observer**

Code to write in **controllerA** :

```
// Add Notification Observer when your view initialise.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(dismissPopup) name:@"DISMISS_POPUP" object:nil];
```

In **viewWillDisappear** remove the notifications observer

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

This method will be called when you Post-notification from your **popupControllerB**

```
-(void)dismissPopup {
[self dismissPopupViewControllerWithanimationType:MJPopupViewAnimationFade];
}
```

And In **popupControllerB**, Where you want to dismiss the Pop-up, write this code.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DISMISS_POPUP" object:nil];
```

Above line of code will call a method written in your **controllerA** and dismiss the pop-up properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dismiss presented `UIViewControllers` you can use this code. I have used this approach to dismiss `presentedViewControllers`. It will dismiss all your `presentedViewControllers` on your `rootViewController`.

```
UIViewController* presVC = self.window.rootViewController;

while (presVC) {
    UIViewController* temp = vc.presentingViewController;
     if (!temp.presentedViewController) {
         [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{}];
         break;
       }
      vc =  temp;
}
```